# Output views_embed_view to Ajax content

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I have a View block. I can print the content with `views_embed_view` function, passing **$display_id**, *contextual filter*, etc.

Now I want the user to click on a point in an image, and with Javascript, show the block in a div. So when the user click on different coordinates of the image, I show different product details in that div.

This should be possible to accomplish using Ajax ( `$(#div-id).html()` or `div_id.innerHTML` ), but my limited experience with Ajax is to retrieve a JSON formated data, not a full HTML block of a View.

How could I get it working? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved it, by using the following code which goes in a custom module.  The problem I had was that it was not rendering anything as there were nested divs. If you play with styles or add some HTML between divs, it will show the data.

The code is available at http://www.seanbuscay.com/ajax-reader-demo/